# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'register_request' not found. 'register_request' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, django-urls

this is a shopping website my login and registration form is not working it is showing that no reverse path found error.
this is my navbar template

```
 <div class="container py-5">
       <p class="text-center">If you already have an account, <a href="{% url 
       'sweet:register_request' %}">login</a> instead.</p>
  </div>
 <div class="container py-5">
    <p class="text-center">Don't have an account? <a href="/register">Create an account</a>. 
    </p>
 </div>
```

login.html
this is my login template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
    
{% load static %}
    
{% block content %}
    
<form method="POST">
       
 {% csrf_token %}
        
{{ login_form }}
       
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
    
</form>
    
{% endblock %}
```

home.html
this is my registration template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
    
{% load static %}
    
{% block content %}
    
<form method="POST">
            
<button class="btn btn-primary"  type="submit">Register</button>
            
{% csrf_token %}
            
{{register_form}}
    
</form>
   
{% endblock %}
```

views.py
register_request is function defined to register the form and login_request is to login into my website

```
def register_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "Registration successful.")
            return redirect('login_request')
        messages.error(request, "Unsuccessful registration. Invalid information.")
    form = NewUserForm()
    return render(request,"home.html",{"register_form": form})


def login_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.info(request, "You are now logged in as {username}.")
                return redirect("base.html")
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html',{"login_form": form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView, LoginView
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
app_name="sweet"
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.allProdCat,name='allProdCat'),
    path('<slug:c_slug>/',views.allProdCat,name='products_by_category'),
    path('<slug:c_slug>/<slug:prod_slug>/', views.ProductDetail, name='ProdCatDetail'),
    path('register/', views.register_request, name="register"),
    path("login/", views.login_request, name="login"),
]
```

forms.py
the form is for registration and login

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from . import models
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class NewUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(NewUserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

this are all my code please help

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get address of `views.register_request` in `{% url 'sweet:register_request' %}` but the name of url path you have chosen is different. You can do one of two options, in both you need to change name.

Option 1:

```
# from
path('register/', views.register_request, name="register"),

# to
path('register/', views.register_request, name="register_request"),
```

Option 2:

```
# from
{% url 'sweet:register_request' %}

# to
{% url 'sweet:register' %}
```

Comment: i tried both of them but pagenot found error

Answer (score 1):

**instead of this:**

```
<div class="container py-5">
       <p class="text-center">If you already have an account, <a href="{% url 
       'sweet:register_request' %}">login</a> instead.</p>
  </div>
 <div class="container py-5">
    <p class="text-center">Don't have an account? <a href="/register">Create an account</a>. 
    </p>
 </div>
```

**Do this:**

```
<div class="container py-5">
       <p class="text-center">If you already have an account, <a href="{% url 
       'sweet:register' %}">login</a> instead.</p>
  </div>
 <div class="container py-5">
    <p class="text-center">Don't have an account? <a href="/register">Create an account</a>. 
    </p>
 </div>
```

Comment: no sir still got an error of page not found

Comment: Please provide settings file now and structure of your project

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'sweet',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
my installed apps in settings.py file

Comment: TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'sweet.context_processors.menu_links',
            ],
        },
    },
]

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS =[os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')]
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')